# Why is the GUID structure declared the way it is?

Tags: guid

In rpc.h, the GUID structure is declared as follows:

```
typedef struct _GUID 
{  
   DWORD Data1;  
   WORD Data2;  
   WORD Data3;  
   BYTE Data[8];
} GUID;
```

I understand Data1, Data2, and Data3.  They define the first, second, and third sets of hex digits when writing out a GUID (XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXX).

What I never understood was why the last 2 groups were declared together in the same byte array.  Wouldn't this have made more sense (and been easier to code against)?

```
typedef struct _GUID 
{  
   DWORD Data1;  
   WORD Data2;  
   WORD Data3;  
   WORD Data4;  
   BYTE Data5[6]; 
} GUID;
```

Anyone know why it is declared this way?

Comment: i would assume it's declared as `4,2,2,8` rather than `4,2,2,2,6` so that the final 8 bytes can be accessed as a 64-bit variable if desired.

Comment: It seems important to distinguish the two structures especially in the case of serializing to a byte stream given that Data[8] from the first definition may look different on the stream than the Data4 Data5[6] combination from the second definition for reasons of endianness.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's because a GUID is a special case of a [UUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UUID).  For information on what all the fields mean, you can look at [RFC 4122](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt).

Answer (score 3):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_Unique_Identifier and http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9629399/apdxa.htm (DCE's orginal representation, you can see the grouping of **bits** there in a table)