# Usage of GUID in C++:

Tags: c#, c++, winapi

I want to ask if declaration of GUID in C++ differs from C#. I encountered this in C#:

```
GUID InterfaceClassGuid = {0x4d1e55b2, 0xf16f, 0x11cf, 0x88, 0xcb, 0x00, 0x11, 0x11, 0x00, 0x00, 0x30};
```

Is this viable in C++? If not how can it be converted? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of `GUID` in `<windows.h>` is compatible with this syntax. It also works in C.

Comment: When i do like that i get red text near InterfaceClassGuid in Debugger Autos like this : 4D1E55B2-F15F-11CF-88CB-001111000030 (in red). Is this normal?

Comment: @AverageAtBest: The red is because the watched value changed (OK, that was the intent of your statement). The format shown is a bit more compact. It leaves out the `0x` and concatenates the last 6 bytes. Still the same value, though.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest perhaps (and convenient too) will be to leverage MS specific [`__declspec(uuid(...))`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/uuid-cpp):

```
class __declspec(uuid("{C1F400A4-3F08-11D3-9F0B-006008039E37}")) NullRenderer;
GUID x = __uuidof(NullRenderer);
```

This way you don't even have to split the GUID components in source code, yet have it as true GUID declaration.

Answer (score 2):

There is no GUID type defined in standard C++. However, you could (and maybe some compiler vendors have) define a `struct GUID` that could be initialized the same way.

**edit**: 
[Microsoft defines GUID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373931%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as follows:

```
typedef struct _GUID {
  DWORD Data1;
  WORD  Data2;
  WORD  Data3;
  BYTE  Data4[8];
} GUID;
```

With this definition, your code should work as it is.

Answer (score 2):

The GUID-structure differs from C#. It is defined

```
typedef struct _GUID 
{  
   DWORD Data1;  
   WORD Data2;  
   WORD Data3;  
   BYTE Data[8];
} GUID;
```

If you want to treat it as a variable you'll do it:

```
GUID guid = {0x4d1e55b2, 0xf16f, 0x11cf, {0x88, 0xcb, 0x00, 0x11, 0x11, 0x00, 0x00, 0x30}};
```

Try it and also look here: [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276524/why-is-the-guid-structure-declared-the-way-it-is)