# C# COM assembly implementing C++ interface

Tags: c#, c++, com, interop

Does anybody know whether the following implementation of a C++ interface in C# is correct, particularly with regards to the marshaling of the GUID type.

The original C++ we are implementing:

```
[
    object,
    pointer_default(unique),
    uuid(Z703B6E9-A050-4C3C-A050-6A5F4EE32767)
]
interface IThing: IUnknown
{
    [propget] HRESULT Prop1([out, retval] GUID* prop1); 
    [propget] HRESULT Prop2([out, retval] EnumProp2* prop2);
    [propget] HRESULT Prop3([out, retval] HSTRING* prop3);
};
```

The converted interface in our C# COM assembly:

```
[ComVisible(true), Guid("Z703B6E9-A050-4C3C-A050-6A5F4EE32767"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IThing
{
    Guid Prop1 { get; }
    EnumProp2 Prop2 { get; }
    string Prop3 { get; }
}
```

The concrete class:

```
public class Thing : IThing
{    
    public Thing(Guid prop1, EnumProp2 prop2, string prop3)
    {
        Prop1 = prop1;
        Prop2 = prop2;
        Prop3 = prop3;
    }

    public Guid Prop1 { get; }
    public EnumProp2 Prop2 { get; }
    public string Prop3 { get; }
}
```

Comment: the Guid structures of C# and the <windows.h> definition of GUID have a different grouping, but they are "binary compatible" as they're both 16 byte long and bytes are ordered consistently: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14891293/1132334
so it should work. do you have any reason to believe your ComVisible interface would be wrong? can you just test it?

Comment: ok looks like it should by a byte[16] which you can get using `Guid.ToByteArray`. [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/guid.cs,b622ef5f6b76c10a) shows that the `Guid` struct is a complex type and does not expose the raw bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the issue was actually not marshaling the `Guid` structure, but the `string`.

It seems that when moving a string from the managed CLR heap to the unmanaged heap, the default marshaling type is UnmanagedType.BStr (unicode character string, length-prefixed) - and the host app in this case required a different marshal type:

```
public string Name { [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.HString)]get; }
```